# How can I get useful information from largest tab-delimited file with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, csv

I have following problem. I have tabdelimited file with more 100 000 records. On every row have 6 and more elements, but i want to get 2 elements from any row.

**Sample structure of the tabdelemited file :**

```
    a1  1       b1      c1      11      111
    a2  2       b2      c2      12      112
    a3  3       b3      c3      13      113
    a4  4       b4      c4      14      114
...........................................................................
```

Following code returned all ellements from this file in array:

```
$f4 = fopen("FILE.TXT", 'r');
        while (($line = fgetcsv($f4, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE)
            if ($line)
                    $arr4[] = $line;
fclose($f4);
```

This code for more 100 000 rows is very very slowly. How can I get the elements they need and the algorithm to be fast?

The output result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => a1 //first column
            [1] => b1 //third column     
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a2
            [1] => b2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a3
            [1] => b3    
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a4
            [1] => b4   
        )
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *but i want to get 2 elements from any row* Can you explain what that means?

Comment: Does *"i want to get 2 elements from any row"* mean you want two specific columns from each row or that you want to search all rows for rows matching conditions on two columns? Or *C) None of the above*?

Comment: Yes, to answer this, we need to know what "any row" means. Every row? A specific row that matches [what? an ID?], or a random row?

Comment: PHP is not perfect for that. You can do some tweaking, but it never will be "fast". If performance matters on this task, you need to get rid of parsing the file all over again. You could use caching or a database.

Comment: I want get two specific columns from each row. For example: the elements  from first column and elements from the third column.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to retrieve 2 of some arbitrary number of columns from each row in a CSV file.  To do this:

```
$f4 = fopen('FILE.TXT', 'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($f4, 0, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $arr4[] = array(
        $line[2], // Use whatever indexes you need for the columns
        $line[3]  // here.
    );
}
fclose($f4);
```

Optionally, you can specify a maximum length as argument #2 to `fgetcsv()` to speed things up a bit.  See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) for more info.

**Edit:** Also, if your column indexes are sequential (e.g. 2, 3 or 4, 5), using [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) might be faster, but you'd have to benchmark it to know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

**2 columns from every row**

If your goal is to get 2 columns from every row, you're going to have to iterate all the rows. It would be best to do whatever operations are needed immediately, rather than dropping rows into an array (as it's going to eat up memory fast if multiple users can hit this script at the same time).

The only way to make this much faster will be to cache the results ahead of time. You could load the CSV into a database table and index the columns, for example.

**2 columns from a row matching an ID**

You can make this fairly fast by doing a regex search, rather than parsing the entire file. For instance, if you put the ID into the first column, you could do something like this:

```
// note that because we use file_get_contents, the file must fit in memory!
// if multiple users are hitting this at the same time, it could be a valid concern
preg_match("/^$sanitized_id/" file_get_contents('filename.csv'), $matches);
if( count($matches) > 1 ) {
   $row_values = explode("\t", $matches[1]);
   var_dump($row_values);
}
else {
   print "No matches";
}
```

Alternately, if you have access to the file ahead of time, you can do the same as above and index the results in a database table, making the search fast and easy.